# LayerSwitcher from OpenLayers doesn't appear

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have 3 layers, which 2 layers are from 2 geojson and 1 layer is OpenStreetMap basemap. 2 layers consider of BusRoutes (have 21 classes from "nama" field) and BusStops (have five classes from "nama" field). How to make layerswitcher using OpenLayers from those data, which every class of BusRoutes and BusStops can fold to dropdown layerswitcher? I already create the script:

```
// Create layer switcher control
const layerSwitcher = new LayerSwitcher({
  target: document.querySelector('#layer-switcher'),
  show_progress: true,
  extent: true,
  trash: true,
  reverse: true,
  groupSelectStyle: 'group',
  activationMode: 'click'
});

// Add layers to layer switcher
layerSwitcher.addLayer(BusRoutes, 'Bus Routes');
layerSwitcher.addLayer(BusStops, 'Bus Stops');
```

But it says:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: u.addLayer is not a function

in developer mode console, which is pointing to this code

```
    const u = new _l({
        target: document.querySelector("#layer-switcher"),
        show_progress: !0,
        extent: !0,
        trash: !0,
        reverse: !0,
        groupSelectStyle: "group",
        activationMode: "click"
    });
    u.addLayer(h, "Bus Routes"),
    u.addLayer(c, "Bus Stops");
```

Comment: Where does this `LayerSwitcher` comes from?. It's not part of vanilla OpenLayers. Please edit your question and add required info.

Comment: Neither the ol-ext or Matt Walker layer switchers have an `addlayer` method.  If you add a layer to the map and it has a `title` in the options (plus `displayInLayerSwitcher` for the ol-ext version) it will appear in the layer switcher https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-tiled-forked-tguqsv?file=/main.js

Comment: Thank you @Mike, for your answer and the provided code. But how to show every class of 'nama' field in the layerswitcher? For example, I have 'nama' column that contains "Route 1", "Route 2", and "Route 3" values. Thank you very much

Comment: A layerswitcher does not filter features within a layer.  You would need to allocate your features into categories and create a layer for each category which shows only that category as in https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-tiled-forked-09gwe8?file=/main.js

Comment: Thank you so much @Mike, it helps me